# React anchor link delims not parsing data

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple anchor / for loop:

```
        <ul className="user-list">
            {this.props.partymembers.map((user, i) => {
                return (
                    <li key={i} className="membername">
                        <a href="/friends/add/{user.id}">{user.username}</a>
                    </li>
                )
            })}
        </ul>
```

But the link just shows up as `/friends/add/{user.id}` instead of `/friends/add/141513531` am I missing something here? Thanks. Username shows fine, but not inside the ""

I managed to solve it by doing

```
<li key={i} className="membername">
  {React.createElement('a', { href: '/friends/add'+user.id}, user.username)}
</li>
```

but that almost seems hacky, is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole attribute needs to be either a string *or* an expression. So something like this:

```
<a href={'/friends/add/' + user.id}>{user.username}</a>
```

If you're using babel to transpile ES6, you can use template strings:

```
<a href={`/friends/add/${user.id}`>{user.username}</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, fantastic I'll mark as answer in 38 seconds.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34583095/how-can-i-use-the-onclick-event-in-react-with-a-variable-element There you go! Sorry the formatting was off in the earlier comment :P